# Find out if user has accepted to receive Push Notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I am using this piece of code to find out if the user has accepted to receive Remote Notifications `UIApplication.sharedApplication().isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications()` - However, testing it on my device, even though I tapped "Don't Allow" - I get `true` and also I get the device token?

On the other hand, in the Settings app => Notifications the app is set not to receive any notifications...

So is there a correct way to find out if user has to has not allowed the app to receive APN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the current notification settings with [currentUserNotificationSettings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/currentUserNotificationSettings):

```
let notificationSettings = UIApplication.sharedApplication().currentUserNotificationSettings()
print("Notification types allowed by user is: \(notificationSettings.types).")
```

If the user has disabled notifications, the types will be `None`.